# SQL Server : full-text search with join

Tags: full-text-search, full-text-indexing

```
<groveling>
```

This is probably something very basic. I'm brand new to full-text indexing and searches and I've been trying to get this to work for hours so please go easy on me :)

```
</groveling>
```

Say I have a table of people with firstname, lastname, address, dob etc...

```
create table mypeople
(
  id int identity(1,1) primary key,
  firstname varchar(100) not null,
  lastname varchar(100) not null,
  address varchar(100) not null
)
```

I have another table that contains information on people I don't want to do business with, known international criminals, people who have frauded my company before etc..

```
create table badguys
(
   id int identity(1,1) primary key,
   firstname varchar(100) null,
   lastname varchar(100) null,
   alias varchar(max) null,
   address varchar(max) null
)
```

I have a fulltext index on my badguy table for firstname,lastname,alias,address. What I need to do is look at all of the firstnames in the mypeople table and see if they are in the badguys table. I've been messing around with different queries for hours and haven't come with anything that works for me.

Comment: why not simply `select mypeople.id from mypeople inner join badguys on mypeople.firstname=badguys.firstname`?

Comment: I want to be able to search through firstname, last name and alias and I need to be able to look for close matches so like b0b should match bob or rob or robert or robbie in all of those fields

Comment: fulltext won't help at all with `b0b==bob` stuff. if you need fuzzy matching, you'll need other tools, like soundex().

Comment: I also need stuff like thesaurus matching, near matches and other queries related to full-text indexes. 
There has got to be a way it iterate through all the first names in the myperson table and do a freetext or contains on the badguys table without using a cursor.

Comment: you can join on a fulltext, e.g. `join badguys on match(badguys.x, badguys.x, etc..) against mypeople.firstname`, but it still won't help at all for "near" matches. fulltext is just a very fancy way of doing "is this string exactly present somewhere in the target string".

Answer (score 0):

There are ways for you to achieve thesaurus matching.
Please refer to this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142491.aspx

To find matches with the full text index use something like this:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM MyPeople AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT FirstName, LastName      
      FROM [MTPS].[dbo].[BadGuys]
      WHERE  CONTAINS((FirstName,LastName), @searchExpr)
)
```